# Does editing tags bump a question to the top of the list?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the "quick tag" editor since I don't have enough (10k?) rep yet. Does editing only the tags using either the quick editor from the question or going to the edit page bump a question to the top of the question list?

The reason I ask is because I want to implement [part of this change](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2052/should-the-software-engineering-and-software-development-tags-exist). I want to go through all questions tagged [software-engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-engineering) and replace them with an appropriate (and hopefully existing tag) that is far more specific as to the areas of software engineering that the question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any edit to a post bumps it. It doesn't matter whether this is from the normal "edit" link or the quick tag edit option available to 10K+ users.

The only exception to this are the [CHAOS team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character) (those with a Ψ after their name) who have been given special "powers" to edit a title (and only a title) without bumping the post.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have any recommendations for tag-changes, then? I don't see any "best practices" here or on Meta SO for how to do sweeping tag changes. The only thing that I can think of is to pace myself (edit ~5 questions, then stop for a while).

Comment: @Thomas - nope, sorry. Feel free to do more than 5 at a time though. Flooding the home page with changes isn't ideal, but I think we get enough traffic to cope.

Comment: Thanks. If it becomes excessive, I would assume a diamond mod would send me a message somehow, and let me know to chill for a bit? I suppose that would be the best option. Also, do you recommend starting newest-first, votes-first, active-first, or unanswered-first? I've never helped with cleaning up a tag before, so I don't know what the best practices are for such a thing.

Comment: @Thomas - I don't really know which way to go. You could go oldest -> newest so that the newest ones reappear on the home page when you are finished.

Comment: @thomas this is also an opportunity for others to look at, vet, and potentially *improve* the bumped questions.. but I agree, try to take it slow, there is no magic way we can help you when it takes a "which tag is more proper?" decision *per question*.

Comment: @Jeff That's a good point, too. So I probably will take it slow. There were 5 asked this week, and 230 questions with the tag. So if I do 10 questions a day, and take a good, hard look at them (including making any minor edits to the title or question to improve them), it'll go very well, I think.